# "the imread function" or "the function imread"

Tags: word-order, proper-nouns

What is the difference between the following sentences? Are both correct? If both are correct, which is more popular?

> The function imread reads images.
>
> The imread function reads images.

Note that "imread" is the name of the function, and that the difference is the order of the words "function" and "imread". I have seen both constructions repetitively in software manuals and source code comments.

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: But conversely, when there is a name, it is common to precede the name by a classifier: "the book _Paradise Lost_, the film _Aliens_, the mountain _Kilimanjaro_". "The function _imread_"  is a very common pattern in technical manuals.

Comment: Please post your other question as a separate post.

Comment: My comment above was a reply to a comment which has since been deleted. The upshot is that there is plenty of precedent for both ways round.

Comment: Just to give you [an example](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html). The page contains both "the built-in function len()," and "the print() function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm know quite a bit about coding and can confirm that both are correct.

Personally if I was going to talk about that function to other programmers then I would say "imread function" but, if I was going to create some documentation about it (this would be a more formal context) then I would put "function imread".

TLDR - Both are correct. If I had to, I'd say "function imread" is more formal but it really doesn't make much of a difference.